# Why i can't delete my array pointer when i declared it with the 'new' keyword

Tags: c++

I don't know if it is the correct title but can someone explain to me why this is happening?

```
class asd {
public:
    asd() {
        const char* bufferX = new char[16];
        const char* bufferY = new char[16];
        const char Player = 'O';
    }

    ~asd() {
        delete[] bufferX;
        delete[] bufferY;
    }
};
```

I'm getting this error: `identifier "bufferY" is undefined`

Comment: You can't access the variable name outside the scope where you declared it.  Did you mean to make class members?

Comment: You should post the code in here rather than attaching screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, @ODYN-Kon I didn't know that i though it will be just easier to post it as a screenshot

Comment: @xXTurner The reason to post the code instead of a screenshot is so that when other people come here in the future, they don't have to go to some other site to understand your question (or the answers). Your image may not be available forever.

Comment: @xXTurner https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @xXTurner Another reason why you don't post images is that someone may want to take your code and run it.  For them to do that, instead of a simple copy and paste, they have to either type the code in, or use an OCR engine to read the image and convert it to text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bufferX and bufferY variables are not declared as class members but rather as variables in the asd() function/constructor and they are deleted when that function exits.

You should declare them as class members if you want to retain them.

Also, please do not post code as images, it makes it harder to help you.

```
class asd
{
    public:
    const char *bufferX, *bufferY;
    const char Player = '0';

    asd()
    {
        bufferX= new char[16];
        bufferY= new char[16];
    }

    ~asd()
    {
        delete[] bufferX;
        delete[] bufferY;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, Yes about the images I thought it will be easier but for the future I will know.

Comment: You probably do not want to make the pointers class members. How do you justify using pointers over, say, `std::array<char, 16>`?

Comment: They aren't "deleted", they just become inaccessible.

Comment: @BenVoigt well the pointers will be "deleted", it is the allocated memory that will remain but be inaccessible, i should have specified that.

Comment: @f9t0: The pointers will be destroyed, yes.  But "delete" implies much more, such as invocation of an `operator delete()` deallocation function.  That won't happen.  Not for what the pointers point to, and not for the storage of the pointers themselves.

Comment: @BenVoigt So, is "lost" the appropriate word then ?

Comment: "lost" doesn't have any special meaning in C++ so you can use it any way you think makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Because your pointers (`bufferX`, `bufferY`) are local to the `asd` constructor.  This means that they are not visible within the destructor, or anywhere outside the constructor.

If you must use raw pointers, you probably want to make the pointers class members.  But it's generally a bad idea to work with raw pointers in C++.  Consider using `std::vector` or `std::array`.

If you must to use `char[]`, then consider using C++14 smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`.  Then you don't need to worry about calling delete.  The memory will be freed automatically as soon as it no longer has any references.

Example:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> bufferX(new char[16]);
```

Then we `asd` gets destroyed, this memory will be freed automatically.

Comment: You probably do not want to make the pointers class members. How do you justify using pointers over, say, `std::array<char, 16>`?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I'm not that experienced in c++ yet. I didn't knew that. Thank you!

Comment: @xXTurner Owning raw pointers are generally a bad idea in C++. Prefer containers like `std::vector` or `std::array`, depending on usecase.